# How to abreviate the headmark in automark

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have to following setup

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\rehead{Chapter \thechapter}
\lohead{\headmark} %% <--- This results in too long marks

\begin{document}
\chapter[xxx really long title xxx xxx really long title xxx xxx really long title xxx]{Study 1}
\label{study1}
\section*{xxx really long title xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx}
\end{document}
```

Since **automark** uses the TOC entry in `\lohead`, it gets 3 lines long which is too much. Is there a way to somehow tweak some latex variables that instead of the long TOC entry the `Study 1` would be taken?

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, did my answer solved you problem? If yes, it would be nice if you accept it. If no, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you activate the klasse option `headings=optiontohead|optiontotoc|optiontoheadandtoc`*, you can use the options `head={…}` and `tocentry={…}` in the optional argument of sectioning macros.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=optiontohead]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for demonstration

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[tocentry={Only in ToC (A)},head={Only in Head (A)}]{Only in Text (A)}
\lipsum
\chapter[Only in Head (B)]{In ToC and Text (B)}
\lipsum
\chapter[head={Only in Head (C)}]{In ToC and Text (C)}
\lipsum
\chapter[tocentry={Only in ToC (D)}]{In Head and Text (D)}
\lipsum
\chapter{Everywhere (E)}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

(*) all possible three settings activate the extended support for the optional argument of sectioning macros. The option you give defines what happens when you use the optional argument as usual.
(the fourth possible value `optiontotocandhead` is just a synonym of `optiontoheadandtoc`)

Comment: I still need to try that out, thanks for the nice repsponse!

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for your feedback. Let me know if I can help ...

Comment: Yes, perfect! I used `headings=optiontohead`